# most efficient way to make a custom horizontal-scrollable grid list?

Tags: android, scroll, grid

[image]

How can I implement something like this so I could customize each view in the grid? (each one its own image, text.. depending on a response from server).
**I prefer not using 3-party libraries, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up Horizontal RecyclerView, and based on the position of the view, you can set background color.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```